# Rolling dice -- prove that $X$ and $5-X$ have the same distribution

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose there'a tetrahedral dice with numbers $1,2,3,4$. Let's denote by $X$ a rolled number. **Prove** that $X$ and $5-x$ have the same distribution.

So, for $X$:
$$F_X(t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t) = 
\begin{cases}
0, &t < 1\\
1/4, & 1 \leq t < 2\\
2/4, & 2 \leq t < 3 \\
3/4, & 3 \leq t < 3 \\
1, & 4 \leq t
\end{cases}
$$
Now, for $Y=5-X$
$$
F_Y(t) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(5-X \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq 5 - t) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X < 5 - t) = 1 - F_X(5-t)^- \\= 1-
\begin{cases}
 0, &5-t <1\\
1/4, & 1 \leq 5-t < 2 \\
2/4, & 2 \leq 5-t < 3\\
3/4, & 3 \leq 5-t < 4\\
1, &  4\leq t
\end{cases} = 
\begin{cases}
 1, &t > 4\\
3/4, & 3 < t \leq 4 \\
2/4, & 2 < t \leq 3\\
1/4, & 1 < t \leq 2\\
0, &  1\leq t
\end{cases}
$$
The problem is that intervals are incorrectly closed. I guess that it is due to the fact that I have $F_X(5-t)^-$, so I cannot explicitly use $F_X(\cdot)$. What shall I do then?

Comment: If you want to take this route, then you can consider treating the cases $t\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ separately. Then you have $F_X=(F_X)^-$ for all other $t$, and four exceptional cases. On the other hand you don't necessarily need to calculate the probability distribution function, since the probability mass function (PMF) will do just fine. I.e. show $P(X=x) = P(5-X=x)$ for all $x$. (Since the distribution is discrete)

Comment: To add to the above comment, you can compute the CDF, but $\mathbb{P}(5-X \in \{1,2,3,4\}) = 1$ because $\mathbb{P}(X\in \{1,2,3,4\}) = 1$. To see this, note that $X=1 \iff 5-X = 4$, $X=2 \iff 5-X = 3$, $X=3 \iff 5-X = 2$, and $X=4 \iff 5-X = 1$. So realizing any range of values outside of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ will have probability $0$.

Comment: This seems much easier than you are making it. For example, $P(5-X=1)=P(X=4)=\frac{1}{4}$. The same argument works for the other outcomes. A discrete distribution is completely defined by assigning probabilities to its outcomes.